# How to force JS script update in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, versioning, browser-cache

I have a js module, let's call it `A`. It uses versioning by appending `?v=xxxxxxxxxxxx` into its URL (like `<script src="/Scripts/A.js?v=637082108844148373"></script>`). `v` changes everytime we make changes in the file.

Here is the code:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string Content(this UrlHelper helper, string filename, bool versioned)
    {
        var result = filename;

        if (versioned)
        {
            var lastWriteTimeToken = CalculateToken(helper.RequestContext.HttpContext, filename);
            result = filename + "?v=" + lastWriteTimeToken;
        }

        return helper.Content(result);
    }
}
```

And then we can use it in Razor views as this:

```
// Sample.cshtml
// ... code omitted for the sake of brevity ...

@section scripts {
    <script type="module" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/A.js", true)"></script>
}

// ... code omitted for the sake of brevity ...
```

The module imports modules `B.js` and `C.js`:

```
// A.js

import {Foo} from "./B.js";
import {Bar} from "./C.js";
```

If I change something in module `A.js`, client browser's cache is busted since we have `?v` parameter which is changing every time we make any changes in `A.js`. But if I change something in module `B.js` or `C.js`, its version remains the same and I have to clear cache manually (`CTRL + F5`) to see the changes.

In other words, we can't use `?v` parameter for the lines:

```
import {Foo} from "./B.js";
import {Bar} from "./C.js";
```

How to solve this problem of cache busting for imported files in MVC 5?

Comment: Why not create a `ScriptBundle` with A, B and C in one instead of importing them in the js file A itself? In MVC you can normally create a bundle in `/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs`. And then if you update one file it will be directly available (and is automatically minimized),

Comment: @VDWWD A, B and C are modules, not just regular JS files. We use `export` and `import` to expose only what we need to and use only what we need in the module.

Answer (score 1):

With ASP.NET Core, you may use the TagHelper attribute: `asp-append-version` to perform cache busting.

```
<script src="/Scripts/A.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP header**

You could use the HTTP header to instruct the browser to `no-cache` or wipe cache after a short time.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

**New paths for B and C**

If you like to stick to versioning, you could also put the modules B and C in a new folder (version number) and rewrite the paths in module A. Of course you don’t want to do this manually, but via a script (that ideally executes on save).

**Transpile A, B and C into a single file**

Easier would be to transpile the bundles into a single file, for which your versioning already works. You can use esbuild with `--bundle` for that or something else - there are multiple options (also extensions that execute “on save”).

Answer (score 0):

I would work backwards from the desired final deployed state of your index.html file. My [Demo SPA](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final) produces this output, but the application code does not need to deal with any cache related concerns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>

        <base href='/spa/' />
        <title>OAuth Demo App</title>

        <link rel='stylesheet' href='bootstrap.min.css?t=1648582395628' integrity='sha256-YvdLHPgkqJ8DVUxjjnGVlMMJtNimJ6dYkowFFvp4kKs='>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='app.css?t=1648582395628' integrity='sha256-B7pu+gcFspulW4zXfgczVtPcEuZ81tZRFYeRciEzWro='>
    <body>
        <div id='root' class='container'></div>

        <script type='module' src='vendor.bundle.js?t=1648582395628' integrity='sha256-g0/+kYJcpXM7K5tvtIwBx//nKV3mCR8Y6NktYGHgpW0='></script>
        <script type='module' src='app.bundle.js?t=1648582395628' integrity='sha256-YY15iWJ0R9wnYkc1BP9yBYMlPNCeGFJBWFhio6z8Y1Q='></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**BUILD STEP**

In my case I am using a [Webpack](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/tree/master/spa/webpack) build step, which keeps the application code simple. Meanwhile application modules depend on each other in a simple way.

**SERVER SIDE TECH**

This will be harder if you are mixing server side and client side code to manage Javascript, and personally I am not a fan of such tech stacks. The same principles apply though, so I would look into bundling options and a build step to solve your problem. The application code should not know anything about cache busting URLs.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, if verbose in the script tag, you could include a list of files to check.

```
<script type="module" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/A.js", true, new string[]{ "~/Scripts/B.js","~/Scripts/C.js"})"></script>
```

Then amend your helper to include those in the token.

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    public static string Content(this UrlHelper helper, string filename, bool versioned, string[] cacheCheck)
    {
        var result = filename;

        if (versioned)
        {
            var cacheChecks = cacheCheck.ToList();
            cacheChecks.Add(filename);
            var lastWriteTimeToken = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in cacheChecks)
            {
                lastWriteTimeToken.Add(CalculateToken(helper.RequestContext.HttpContext, item));
            }
            result = filename + "?v=" + String.Join("", lastWriteTimeToken.ToArray());
        }

        return helper.Content(result);
    }
}
```

**Untested** :)

Comment: But those files aren't included using `<script>` tag but imported in JS sources of other modules

Comment: Yes, exactly. So you have to tell the path builder to check other files. It’s not an ideal situation, but neither is the problem at hand.